# Kendo grid server side grouping

Tags: nhibernate, kendo-grid, grouping, queryover

I am using Asp net 5, NHibernate 3.3 and Kendo UI MVC wrapper for grid to render the table of client orders. There are lots of orders in database already and the number is constantly growing. So I decided to use server side paging to avoid fetching all orders from database. As far as I know you can't do paging manually and delegate filtering, sorting and grouping to ToDataSourceResult method. It's either all or nothing. Therefore I made an attempt to implement so called ['custom binding'](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding). No problem until I get to grouping. I need to group first, then sort inside of a group, then extract data for specific page and all that without loading all data to memory. My code is something like this (I put it all in one piece to simplify reading):

```
var orderList = CurrentSession.QueryOver<Order>();

// Filtering. Filter is a search string obtained from DataSourceRequest
var disjunction = new Disjunction();
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Order>(e => e.Number).IsLike("%" + filter + "%"));
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Order>(e => e.Customer).IsLike("%" + filter + "%"));
orderList = orderList.Where(disjunction);

// Sorting. sortColumn is also from DataSourceRequest
switch (sortColumn)
{
        case "Number":
            orderList = orderList.OrderBy(x => x.Number).Desc;
            break;
        case "GeneralInfo.LastChangeDate":
            orderList = orderList.OrderBy(x => x.LastChangeDate).Desc;
            break;
        default:
            orderList = orderList.OrderBy(x => x.Number).Desc;
            break;
     }
}

// Total is required for kendo grid when you do paging manually
var total = orderList.RowCount();


var orders = orderList
    .Fetch(x => x.OrderGoods).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.OrderComments).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Documents).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Partner).Eager
    .Skip((request.Page - 1)*request.PageSize).Take(request.PageSize).List();
```

I will be glad to have any advice on how to add grouping here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I worked for literally months to figure out server-side grouping using the Kendo DataSource with a Kendo Grid. Paging, sorting and filtering were fairly easy. But for whatever reason, Telerik did not offer sufficient support documentation for such a critical LOB process as grouping. I’m glad you posted this question so I’d have an opportunity to share my code.

**The Solution**

Basically, the solution comes down to knowing 2 key parts, and they can be viewed in the following sample project: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygtk8rwl1hwjvth/KendoServerGrouping.zip?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j1j5wazf678vvyv/AABfveWU_7pJvrrJ4Jd2GW1Xa)

There is a single web application project in the Visual Studio (2012 | 2013) solution you’re downloading, which contains a reference to the Kendo.Mvc library. You can download the latest *UI for ASP.NET* binaries from Telerik's Control Panel installation program. The binaries will be located in the following Windows directory after install: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET MVC [Telerik Release Version]\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\ [Your Version of MVC]\Kendo.Mvc.dll**.

**Note**: My solution uses Telerik’s MVC transport mechanism, which provides full-fledged server-side paging, filtering, sorting and, most notably, grouping. **However, I use pure JavaScript to configure the Kendo DataSource and not the MVC wrappers**. Still, I've recently [found a link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/webapi-editing) in Telerik's documentation that shows the MVC wrapper declaration in Razor/ASPX.

**The Server Magic**

Basically, the first part of the ***magic*** is the following server side code, residing in the sample WebApi controller in the **KendoServerGrouping.Web\Controllers** directory:

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "ASPNETMVC-AJAX")]
    public Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult GetAllAccounts([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var kendoRequest = new Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest
        {
            Page = request.Page,
            PageSize = request.PageSize,
            Filters = request.Filters,
            Sorts = request.Sorts,
            Groups = request.Groups,
            Aggregates = request.Aggregates
        };

        // Set this to your ORM or other data source
        IQueryable accounts = dbContext.Accounts;

        /*
           The data source can even be a MongoDB collection using the
           .AsQueryable() extension and the MongoDB C# driver

           var accounts = collection.FindAllAs<Account>().AsQueryable();
        */

        var data = accounts.ToDataSourceResult(kendoRequest);

        var result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            AggregateResults = data.AggregateResults,
            Data = data.Data,
            Errors = data.Errors,
            Total = data.Total
        };

        return result;
    }
```

This is all you’ll need for any of the four server-side actions that the grid will handle auto-magically when the user interacts with it. Pay special attention to the AcceptVerbs attribute above the method; it must include the **“ASPNETMVC-AJAX”** attribute for the DataSourceRequest input parameter to work properly. `ToDataSourceResult()` is an extension provided by recent versions of the Kendo.Mvc.dll library, which I pointed to earlier.

The code above will (to my knowledge) work with any IQueryable data source, such as those from ORMs (I've tested Entity Framework and Telerik Data Access/Open Access). I've also been able to group a MongoDB collection using the MongoDB C# driver. However, **this is meant as a proof-of-concept, and it has not been tested for performance**.

For the purposes of this example, there is static data source in the WebAPI controller to fake an IQueryable collection. Naturally, you can **delete the static data from lines 45-57 when you've swapped in your own data source**.

**The Client Magic**

The Kendo DataSource automatically passes in a specialized DataSourceRequest object from the grid containing all the parameters for server-side paging, filtering, sorting and grouping, ***provided*** you wrap your DataSource schema inside the following JavaScript:

```
schema: $.extend(true, {}, kendo.data.schemas["aspnetmvc-ajax"], {
});
```

**This was perhaps the single most elusive line of code I’ve ever tracked down.** It took about a dozen exchanges with Telerik over several months to get them to cough it up. And even then, it was by pure chance that it was revealed. Why such a critical nuance was absent in their documentation is beyond me.

Carefully review each of the Kendo DataSource configuration settings toward the bottom half of `index.html` file. Most importantly, pay attention to what isn’t there, such as the `batch` and `mvcTransport` options. Including the latter option somehow negates the above **“aspnetmvc-ajax”** schema attribute.

In the DataSource's **parmaterMap** function, make note that when – and only when - performing a read operation, the following line must be present:

```
return mvcTransport.parameterMap(options, operation);
```

You will also want to be sure to include this in your HTML, before the DataSource executes:

```
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/[Version]/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

**The End Result**

Run the **KendoServerGrouping.Web** project (**index.html**) and, if all goes well, a grid will be populated with 5 records containing **AccountId**, **AccountName**, **AccountTypeCode** and **CreatedOn** fields. If you set the number of visible grid rows to **2** and group by **AccountTypeCode** or **CreatedOn**, you’ll see that the grouping traverses the paging, which I believe is the end result you are looking for.

I hope the sample project works and is a good fit for your situation. Please let me know if you have any questions, and I’ll do my best to help.

P.S. This is my first post to SO, so please go easy on me if something isn’t up to SO standards. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer! The sample project you provided works just fine and it demonstrates the behaviour I need. It will be an excellent starting point. By the way I am very surprised to see that solution is so tricky. Telerik definitely have some space for improvement here.

Comment: I'm so glad it worked out! I completely agree about the solution being tricky; it shouldn't have to be this hard to perform server-side grouping. Good luck going forward!

Comment: Instead of using DataSourceRequest from Telerik, you can also try to use [KendoGridBinderEx](https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx)

Comment: @Stef thank you for advice. I actually came across this package a while ago, though I didn't pay much attention to it since it is not very popular. I suppose I would give it a better look.

Comment: @vsevolod, there are two version from this package, the original **KendoGridBinder** and my updated version **KendoGridBinderEx**.

Comment: @Stef I looked at KendoGridBinderEx back when I was searching for a solution, but for one reason or another (it's been a while), it did not work for me. But, that's not saying that it wouldn't now.

I downloaded the GitHub project, but there appears to be a problem. When changing the grid page size of the Dynamic Grouping sample (by editing IndexGrouped.cshtml) so that only 1 record shows at a time, performing grouping on 'Company' results in 12 pages, 9 of them blank, with only 3 pages displaying records for company M-1 and M-2 (2 pages and 1 page, respectively). Can you explain why this is?

Comment: @AaronJessen, thanks for your comment, can you please add this as an issue to my github project? And if possible add some more code-details.

Comment: you save my day :D Thanks full

Comment: I've downloaded your app sample, thanks for your help!  But how to actually do the GroupBy on the Server? If you change `IQueryable accounts = accountList.` to `IQueryable accounts = accountList.GroupBy(x => x.AccountTypeCode).` the response is blank groups.  This makes me think I need to return [a structure like this from Kendo UI docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.groups)

Comment: @jmb.mage The GroupBy (and other server-side functions of Filter, Sort and Page) are handled entirely behind-the-scenes by `Kendo.Mvc.dll`. That is to say, you don't have to manually process your `IQueryable` collection, so long as your code contains the solution above, most notably the "Client Magic" line of `schema: $.extend(true, {}, kendo.data.schemas["aspnetmvc-ajax"], {});`. This causes the DataSource to pass to the server a specially-structured request (with GroupBy clauses), and, via `accounts.ToDataSourceResult()`, `Kendo.Mvc` will return a specially-structured response for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add onto @aaron-jessen answer with [this jewel I found on Telerik's forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/datasourcerequest-filters-and-sorts-fields-null-here-is-the-solution):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",  // If missing may cause NULL values in ApiController
  }
})
```

Comment: Using this `type: "aspnetmvc-ajax"` means Kendo UI Grid will ignore `parameterMap: function() {...}`.   Instead use the `dataSource.transport.read.data: function(e) {...}`