# Kendo GRID sorting, grouping functionality

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

Does Kendo Sorting, Grouping Client side or Server Side? How does it work if all the records are fetched at once or the data is loaded in parts. I tried verifying but was not able to conclude with the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either client or server side.

For server side (i.e. data loaded in parts):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-implement-paging-sorting-filtering-and-grouping

For client side (i.e. all data fetched at once):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-can-i-configure-the-grid-to-perform-paging-sorting-filtering-and-grouping-in-memory

Customised server side - e.g. where you don't have an IQueryable model for your grid data:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding

Comment: Do you know if, when customizing server side bindings using Ajax, you are forced to implement all of the server side functionality yourself or are you free to only implement part of it? Say I wanted to handle grouping myself but allow filtering and paging to be handled automatically via the DataSourceRequest & DataSourceResult. It's not immediately clear to me looking at the documentation for custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do client side binding (AJAX) binding, it will retrieve the data in parts that it needs, just make sure to not put `.ServerFiltering(false)` (and other similar methods) in your `DataSource` configuration.

Also, in your controller, use the `.ToDataSource()` extension method when returning the data, like this:

```
public ActionResult GetTasks([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var tasks = _db.Tasks; // however you want to get your data

    return Json(tasks.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior .AllowGet);
}
```

Note that as iandayman mentioned, you'll want to use an `IQueryable<T>` datasource for this to work properly and defer the paging/sorting/filtering operations to the database.

If you want to do a Server side binding, you can do that as well and using the IQueryable datasource and it will also defer execution to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@iandayman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049834/2432724), it is possible to fetch all the records at once to perform client-side processing, but for performance reasons on larger data sets, I recommend fetching data from the server in one page-result at a time.

The sorting, filtering, paging and grouping can be performed server-side, as outlined in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688299/2432724), which uses the `Kendo.Mvc` library from Telerik and IQueryable server-side data source, such as Entity Framework or Telerik Data Access.

Bear in mind that my answer also makes use of a pure-JavaScript Kendo DataSource declaration, rather than MVC wrappers, as it gave me better granular control over all DataSource options, when I first wrote my solution. Telerik may have improved the wrappers since then (see Telerik's MVC approach [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-implement-paging-sorting-filtering-and-grouping) or their WebApi approach using the wrappers [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/webapi-editing)).