# Kendo UI Grid Server Side Grouping with LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, kendo-grid

What needs to be done in between using a LINQ .GroupBy() and the Kendo UI Grid consuming the data as if it Grouped it itself?

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649952/kendo-grid-server-side-grouping) and [this Kendo UI Grid doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.groups) it looks like if I am to do server side grouping BEFORE I return the JSON response to the Grid that I have to return the response and then in the JavaScript Grid options, filter it through a configuration-schema.groups mapping function to get the Grid to consume it.

**Example**
Controller Code

```
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "ASPNETMVC-AJAX")]
    public Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult IndexDataSource(
        [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        // do something to get a query result and generate a kendoRequest

        var data = queryResult.DataList.AsQueryable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Symbol)  //  *** IS THIS RIGHT? *** 
            .ToDataSourceResult(kendoRequest);

        var result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            AggregateResults = data.AggregateResults,
            Data = data.Data,
            Errors = data.Errors,
            Total = queryResult.TotalCount
        };

        return result;
    }
```

Then in my Grid **DataSource** options:

```
var gridDataSourceOptions = {
        autoLoad: true,
        //autoSync: true,
        //batch: false,
        error: function (e) {
            // console.error("dataSource error: " + e);
            debugger;
        },
        pageable: {
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: $.extend(true, {}, kendo.data.schemas["aspnetmvc-ajax"], {
            aggregates: function (data) {
                return data.AggregateResults;
            },
            data: function (data) {
                return data.Data;
            },

            // something

            groups: function (response) {
                return MapGroupResponse(response);  // *** Important ***
            }
        }),
        group: {
            field: groupField
        }, 
        serverAggregates: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverGrouping: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: 'multiple',
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        transport: {
            // something
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                // something
            }
        },
    };
```

And then the mama-jamma function to do the magic of converting my LINQ .GroupBy() to what I guess is the Kendo UI Grid's format.

```
var groupField = "Symbol";

function MapGroupResponse (response) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(response.Data, function (index, item) {
        result.push({
            aggregates: null,
            field: groupField,
            value: item[0][groupField],
            hasSubgroups: false, // true if there are subgroups
            items: item
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```

This works in that it gets the data through and there are no exceptions & errors, however the Grid does not load anything.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? if so, can you please share ?

Comment: I worked on this around June 2016.  Back then there was no solution, you must rely on the Kendo .dll to do the grouping.  I tried to replicate it on my own, but the structure they generate is complicated, it was easier to let them do it.