# Kendo grid grouping list load on demand

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

i have many groups on grid and each groups has many record, so item list is took many time to load.
i want grid list is loaded on demand when the user clicks the group.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either you let Javascript do the grouping or return the data grouped (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688299/4944034). But this won't change the amount of data and will not reduce the time it takes to do that.

I suggest you to use detail templates as shown on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate The content of a detail template will be loaded on demand. It's not exactly a grouping but it might do the trick for you.